# UWP app always uses front camera

Tags: uwp, .net-core

I need to scan a bar code which obviously works a little better if the user can see what he's aiming for. Though I explicitly set the rear camera as capture device my surface always enables the front camera.

I debugged it and it does actually select the rear camera, provides it's id to the `MediaCapture` object for initialization but it does not work in the end.

```
var cameraDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
var backfacing =
    cameraDevices.FirstOrDefault(c => c.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Panel.Back);

var preferred = backfacing ?? cameraDevices.FirstOrDefault();
// TODO: Change into UI feedback instead
if (preferred == null) throw new Exception("No camera available.");

_capture = new MediaCapture();
_capture.Failed += CaptureOnFailed;
_capture.RecordLimitationExceeded += CaptureOnRecordLimitationExceeded;

try
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        _request = new DisplayRequest();
        _request.RequestActive();
        DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
    });

    await _capture.InitializeAsync(
        new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
        {
            VideoDeviceId = preferred.Id,
            SourceGroup = selectedGroup,
            MemoryPreference = MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Cpu,
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video
        });

    var colorFrameSource = _capture.FrameSources[colorInfo.Id];
    var preferredFormat = colorFrameSource.SupportedFormats.FirstOrDefault(format => format.VideoFormat.Width >= 720);

    if (preferredFormat == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Format not supported.");
    }

    await colorFrameSource.SetFormatAsync(preferredFormat);

    _frameReader = await _capture.CreateFrameReaderAsync(colorFrameSource);
    _frameReader.FrameArrived += FrameReaderOnFrameArrived;
    await _frameReader.StartAsync();
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    // No permission for camera usage
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

Why so? What can I do to change it? I don't find any information on that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You just choose the camera that is on the front panel of the device by the following code line:

```
var backfacing = cameraDevices.FirstOrDefault(c => c.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Panel.Front);
```

So that it use the front camera. If you want to use the camera that is on the back panel, you should set the [`EnclosureLocation.Panel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.enclosurelocation) property to [`Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.panel)

```
var frameSourceGroups = await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync();
var selectedGroupObjects = frameSourceGroups.Select(group =>
new
{
    sourceGroup = group,
    colorSourceInfo = group.SourceInfos.FirstOrDefault((sourceInfo) =>
    {
        return sourceInfo.MediaStreamType == MediaStreamType.VideoPreview
        && sourceInfo.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Color
        && sourceInfo.DeviceInformation?.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back;
    })
}).Where(t => t.colorSourceInfo != null)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Details please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFrames) which provides the samples that both work with front and back camera well.

Comment: Yeah well... my fail. I actually had it use *Back* but in all frustration I ended up trying if setting it to *Front* would change anything. Though I explicitly set "Back" and it also says "Microsoft Rear Camera" or so, it does use the front camera ... *Fixed that now in the code above*

Comment: @SharpShade,did you mean you still have issues if change it to `Back`? What's the result if you test the official sample in your device?

Comment: Haven't tried the official sample, but since this is the exact code MSDN suggests to use, I guess it would fail there too. And yes, even when I set it to Back, it does use the front camera. I'll try that next week when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Okay, I've tried the official samples and though they're doing the exact same thing: with them it works whereas my app just won't use the back-facing camera. I really don't get it ...